# Worklight Server dependencies servlet

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am crating WorkLightAuthenticator, but the dependecies are in trouble.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

I include the library WebSphere Application Server V.8.5, but it did not come with the jars, like the image below.

[image]

In another project. I did not have this problem. like the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's not working for me either. Could you provide which version of worklight are you working with ?

Meanwhile, as a workaround, the Liberty jars are located in:

{$YOURWORKSPACE}/com.worklight.studio.plugin_{$SOME_BUILDNUMER_FOR_YOUR_WORKLIGHT}/liberty/wlp/lib

Comment: I am using Worklgiht 6.1.0

Comment: I see. Is your other project on 6.0 by any chance ? Also, the correct path for the jars should be: {YOUR_ECLIPSE_FOLDER}/plugins/com.worklight.studio.plugin_{$SOME_BUILDNUMER_FOR_YOUR_WORKLIGHT}/liberty/wlp/lib

Comment: The liberty jars are in the way you commented.Both projects are on 6.1.0. The difference is that the project I'm with problems on the libs, was created in Worklight 6.0, then was upgraded to 6.1

Comment: Interesting, I was able to get it work in worklight 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in 6.1.0.1. Please update if possible. The Consumer Edition and Enterprise editions are available here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037219

If you're using developer edition, you could upgrade from within Eclipse.